# Generating notification when the copy of text occurs

Tags: android, android-service

Here is my code that i write in the service class in the oncreate method..

```
if (mCM.hasText()) {
            newClip = mCM.getText().toString();
            if (!newClip.equals(mOldClip)) {
                Log.i("Text:","detect new text clip: " + newClip.toString());
                mOldClip = newClip;


                Log.i("New Text: ",
                        "new text clip inserted: " + newClip.toString());
            }
        }

        super.onCreate();
```

What i want is that when i copy some text a notification occurs or a toast will displayed.

Is it possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you have any activity in your application, just store that activity's context in your class which will extend `Application` like `public class MyClass extends Application{...` and have a public static instance of that activity inside that class like `public static Activity instance;`. Now in `onCreate()` of your activity, just set that instance `MyClass.instance = this;`. Now you have an activity instance and you can now show any toast or dialog anywhere.

Comment: C'mon man. Get sporty. Dig it out. This is not a source code repository. You have any activity in your application? If yes, please attach its onCreate() method with the question.

Comment: I am not using any activity i just extend my class with the service and change in manifest file... I also tried to call my service with broad cast service. By starting the intent.

Comment: Then you may even think of creating a transparent activity just for gettings some activity intent. And set its theme to `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay"`